# Add field to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have created a crystal report, in that i have missed one field at the design time, now i realized that and trying to insert, but the value is not displayed while the report will open. what is the problem in that? how can i correct that. Please help me.

Comment: Which method you have used to bind crystal report ? Or Can you please write your code over here ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to select set datasource location in order to update the fields, refer to this tutorial for more info.

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/7070ebe4-ca28-2e10-d9ad-c11039edbd9a&overridelayout=true